# Better way to list all directories in Python other than self?

Tags: python

I would like to get a list of all the directories inside `IMAGE_DIRECTORY` not including itself. Checking every entry seems suboptimal. Is there a better way to do this?

```
   for dir in [x[0] for x in os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)]:
        if(dir != IMAGE_DIRECTORY):
            files = [dir + "/" +  file for file in os.listdir(dir)]            
            list_of_files.extend(files)
```

---

Just wanted to say thanks for the diverse array of answers! So many different responses so quickly!

Comment: first improvement would be to use generator expressions instead of list generators

Comment: If you want all directories *excluding* the root, wouldn't the second part of the return be more use to you than the first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just skip the first element:

```
walker = iter(os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY))
next(walker)
for path, files, _ in walker:
    list_of_files.extend(os.path.join(path, f) in files)
```

Comment: the 3rd bit is actually subdirectories ... so thats what he should be using ... his code is extending files ... but his question doesnt seem to have anything to do with files... just getting a list of directories ... also im pretty sure os.walk is a generator so not sure about wrapping it in iter

Comment: This is almost what I want, except what I really want is an os.listdir on every subdirectory of IMAGE_DIRECTORY. Thanks. I had forgotten about `next`

Comment: @sunny: os.walk is already listing all files, no need for os.listdir.

Comment: @Daniel but that will include files in the root directory. I want all files in each directory contained in the root directory but not the files in the root directory itself

Comment: @sunny: no, it doesn't.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_subdirs(start_dir):
    return (os.path.join(start_dir,x) for x in next(os.walk(start_dir))[1])

for subdir in get_subdirs(IMAGE_DIR):
    for fname in next(os.walk(subdir))[2]:
        print os.path.join(subdir,fname)
```

note that this is not recursive it returns all the directories immediately under the startdir

or just

```
print next(os.walk(start_dir))[1]
```

Comment: thanks but this includes files not just subdirectories

Comment: to quote you __I would like to get a list of all the directories inside IMAGE_DIRECTORY__ ... but ok no problem ... so do you also want it to be recursive?

Comment: No I meant that I want files excluded. I don't want it to be recursive.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do it in a single line

```
print ['/'.join(d.split('/')[1:]) for d in [x[0] for x in os.walk(IMAGE_DIRECTORY)] if d != IMAGE_DIRECTORY]
```

Comment: putting it all in one line doesnt really make it better or decrease the complexity